# why can't visual studio 2015 resolve dqword when compiling .asm?

Tags: visual-studio, assembly, sse

I wanted to compile my `strlen_sse.asm` to accomplish a function `strlen_sse`,which has the same function as `strlen` but more quick. And my code is below:

```
.CODE
EQUAL_EACH = 00001000b
strlen_sse PROC
;ecx = string
mov eax, -16
mov edx, ecx
pxor xmm0, xmm0

STRLEN_LOOP:
    add eax, 16
    PcmpIstrI xmm0, dqword[edx+eax], EQUAL_EACH
    jnz STRLEN_LOOP

add eax, ecx
ret

strlen_sse ENDP
END
```

I have set the command line and other properties like the picture below:[image]

In the picture `命令行` is what the `command line` is in Chinese. and `输出` is the same as `Output`
When I built the project I got messages below:

```
1>  Performing Custom Build Tools
1>  Microsoft (R) Macro Assembler (x64) Version 14.00.23026.0
1>  Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
1>
1>   Assembling: strlen_sse.asm
1>strlen_sse.asm(13): error A2006: undefined symbol : dqword
```

How to solve it?

Comment: You could leave out the explicit size, since one of the operands is an xmm register.  So it knows you mean a 128bit octo-word.  (I've see `oword` used sometimes, but maybe only in documentation or manuals.  `xmmword` is much more likely to work in asm source code.)

Comment: Yeah, `xmmword ptr` should be used instead of `dqword`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what do you mean by `dqword`. I guess you are trying to use assembly code intended for some other assembler. I should use `XMMWORD PTR` prefix for a memory operand of 128-bit size in masm.

Here is the modified code which compiles with `ml.exe` and `ml64.exe`:

```
tmp SEGMENT

strlen_sse PROC
;ecx = string
mov eax, -16
mov edx, ecx
pxor xmm0, xmm0
STRLEN_LOOP:
    add eax, 16
    PcmpIstrI xmm0, xmmword ptr [edx+eax], 00001000b
    jnz STRLEN_LOOP
    add eax, ecx
ret
strlen_sse ENDP

tmp ENDS
END
```

**Beware:** I have no idea whether it works properly or not.

Comment: Thanks, I used the code from internet, whose url is [strcmp and strlen using sse4.2](http://www.strchr.com/strcmp_and_strlen_using_sse_4.2), and in it `dqword` is used. Now I know the reason. But now I have some other problems and I will post a new question.